# Male configured 'outlet'

Tags: electrical

All I can find is a female configuration like this, but need a male configuration.:
BougeRV 50 Amp RV Power Outlet Box,Enclosed Lockable Weatherproof Outdoor Electrical Nema 14-50R Receptacle,125/250 Volt For Temporary Hookup RV Camper Travel Trailer Motorhome Electric Car Generator
Is there such an exterior box like this with male configuration?

Comment: If you mean something like a "plug" except sticking out of a box instead of on the end of a cable, you're probably not going to find anything like that. The plug goes on the load, the receptacle goes on the power supply. Otherwise the power source would have exposed high voltage pins, which definitely violates NEC/NFPA code and is a safety and fire hazard. Can you edit the question to explain the context of why you want this? Maybe there's a better solution if we can see the big picture.

Comment: @MarkU Note his " ... For Temporary Hookup RV Camper Travel Trailer Motorhome Electric Car Generator I ..." - > sounds lethal.

Comment: For marine use there are boat-mountable shore power inlets to mate with 30 and 50 Amp twist-lock shore power cords - should be similar things in the RV market.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  (!) While the term you use to describe a male-male cable is understood, it is liable to cause extreme reaction and I very strongly recommend you delete it immediately.  (2) The arrangement you suggest is more dangerous than that proposed by the OP as, whereas in his configuration the accessible male pins are able to be isolated with interlocks, the use of a male - male cable with live pins is not readily protectible against with certainty (except with complex monitoring and control systems.

Comment: I see no need for Drama.  When We had a winter extended power failure one year, users would employ this method to prevent pipes from freezing with the mains breakers off and powered by a car Inverter for the furnace. Obviously inserting the inactive end 1st.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 You may see no need for drama, but unfortunately there is a major risk that you are inviting it. You can continue to conduct a social-experiment in this was if you wish, but from the substantial material I have read in the past year across the whole of SE, on what material is liable to be found offensive, the experiment seems highly inadvisable.

Comment: Ideally anaphrodic connectors would be used, but not common for Household use.

Comment: @mrcaptainbox - You can achieve your aim with a good degree of safety and using standard components by. - Providing a standard M-F cable from your car  power source 2. Providing a minimum length M-M cable. 3. Providing a F outlet at the RV. 4. Connecting the Car cable to the RV outlet using the m-m short cable. 5. Critically providing an interlock sealed housing for the connections in step 4 so that user accessible pins are never live / user-accessible pins are never exposed. || Electrically this solution is technically inferior in that it involves one extra plug together connection.

Comment: ... but it uses standard parts throughout.

Comment: Why pretend we don’t call plugs and jacks which can be either sexist labels Male <> Female? It’s just pro symbolism commonplace with no bias.  We’re very open minded in Canada.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108558/discussion-between-russell-mcmahon-and-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Answer (score 2):

Such connectors are readily available. Search for "generator power inlet". Here's just one example, from [Northern Tool](https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200220924_200220924):

[image: photo]

Of course, when you install one of these, it MUST be wired so that it can only connect to loads, not to other power sources! That's what a whole-system or per-circuit transfer switch is for. Here's a small one that happens to have the connector built into it, from Reliance, via [Grainger](https://www.grainger.com/product/2KEP5):

[image: photo]

Comment: That seems to be the problem with the printed word. Car should never have been a part of that.

Comment: I never mentioned car. Were you trying to comment on [Russell's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502297/11683)?

Comment: You may be able to find a manual transfer switch with a pre-installed power inlet.

Comment: @mkeith: You mean, like the one in my second picture?

Comment: Yes @DaveTweed LOL.

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed description of the actual requirement would be useful.

If as it sounds, you are wishing to use this receptacle to transfer power from an electric car-generator to a load then it will need to be accomplished (in any real world situation) by a means that NEVER exposes mains AC on bare contacts that can ever be 'touched' when energised.

You can achieve your aim with a good degree of safety and using standard components by.

Energy source = car generator 
Energy load = RV.

- Providing a standard female outlet at the car-generator and power inlet at the RV.
  The use of a female inlet at the RV is non standard but electrically safe and uses an available component.
- Providing a standard M-F cable from your car-generator power source
- Providing a minimum length M-M cable to be used in an "electrically safe space" at the RV as described below .
  In any but this application that item is potentially lethal and a means of physically retaining it in its safe area of use 'would be wise'.
- Connecting the car-generator  cable to the RV outlet using the M-M short cable.
- **Critically** - providing an interlock sealed housing for the connections in the previous step so that

  - user accessible pins are never live =
  - live pins are never user-accessible

Electrically this solution is technically inferior to using a male receptacle on the RV for incoming energy, as it involves one extra plug-together connection, but it uses standard parts throughout. Whether it "meets code" depends on the regulatory authority. But, its safe, and uses standard components.